# jQuery: Record element moves in Array and check how it was by Array index

Tags: jquery, arrays

I wanted to record element `#inner`'s move by Array **step[step order][each target child length]**,

moving `#inner` from top `.target` to middle `.target` supposed to create an Array like this:

```
(t1= target 1,1 = #inner length)

    doc ready:  [step[0][t1=1,t2=0,t3=0]] 
    after move: [step[0][t1=1,t2=0,t3=0],
                 step[1][t1=0,t2=1,t3=0]]
```

but in my [fiddle example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cheeray/h023dffu/), it goes like this:

```
doc ready:  [step[0][t1=1,t2=0,t3=0]] 
after move: [step[0][t1=0,t2=1,t3=0],
             step[1][t1=0,t2=1,t3=0]]
```

thank you for helping me out in advance.

javascript:

```
var step =[];                //step is a record of changes in #test.
step.push($('.target'))      //step[0] is status of .target at very beginning.

$('.target').on('click',function(){
                     $('#inner').appendTo(this)  //move #inner
                     step.push($('.target'))     //record this move.
                     for ( var i = 0; i < step.length; i++ ){  // step[] loop
                             $('#result').append('step  ',i,': ')
                     // .target loop                                 
                     $('.target').each(function(){$('#result').append($(this).attr('id')+"="+$(this).children('#inner').length+",")}) 
                             $('#result').append('<br/>')
                                 }
                             $('#result').append('...................................<br/>')
            })
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="target" id="t1"><div id="inner"></div></div>
<div class="target" id="t2"></div>
<div class="target" id="t3"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.target {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #666;
}
#inner {
    background-color: #33F;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this line:

```
step.push($('.target')) //record this move.
```

you are pushing a reference to a jQuery set of those elements, not a copy of their state which I believe is what you want. Because you are pushing a *reference* to those elements, printing out the list of moves in `step` will just print the current state of each of the `.target` elements over and over.

To get a copy of each target's state with each move, you can store this data in an array of objects like this: (Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/nbg2xaoh/)

```js
var step = []; //step is a record of changes in #test.

$('.target').on('click', function() {
  $('#inner').appendTo(this) //move #inner
  saveStep(); // record this step
  renderSteps(); // show steps history
})

function saveStep() {
  var newStep = {};
  $(".target").each(function() {
    newStep[this.id] = $(this).children().length;
  });
  step.push(newStep);
}

function renderSteps() {
  $.each(step, function(idx, item) {
    var output = [];
    for (var prop in item) {
      output[output.length] = prop + "=" + item[prop];
    }
    $("#result").append("step " + idx.toString() + ": " + output.join(',') + "<br/>");
  });
  $("#result").append("..................................<br/>");
}

saveStep(); // save intial state; step[0] is status of .target at very beginning.
renderSteps(); // display beginning state
```

```css
.target {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #666;
}
#inner {
  background-color: #33F;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="target" id="t1">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="target" id="t2"></div>
<div class="target" id="t3"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: It would be better to have the initial result be generated by javascript and not be hardcoded. Other than that, great answer. +1

Comment: Thanks, I agree. It now calls `saveStep` and `renderSteps` at the beginning to automate the initial setup and display.

Comment: Solving this problem and pointed out the **reference vs state** is more than just a solution, it also builds me a fundamental concept for the future, a big thank to you :)